# Is there anyway to automatically make a TextView go to a new line after a certain amount of characters?

Tags: android, newline, textview, character, maxlength

I can do this programmatically, but it is really inefficient, and also time consuming if I ever need to do it for multiple TextViews.

I want a TextView to go to a new line after 15 characters, every 15 characters. I tried using `android:maxLength="15"` but that just stopped the string at 15 characters. No new line or anything.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `android:maxEms` to specify a maximum amount of characters in conjunction with `android:singleLine="false"`.

Comment: I don't think that we need to use android:singleLine="false" also maxEms is okay.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I know of is going to be doing it programmatically. Since you worry about having to do it on multiple TextViews I would create a class that sublcasses TextView. Inside there do your logic to break to a new line on every 15th character. You can then use this new TextView in your layouts.